# How shape parameters are connected with mean, variance, skewness and kurtosis of generalized gamma distribution

Tags: distributions, python, gamma-distribution, skewness, kurtosis

I am writing a code in python that can generate probability distribution with given mean (m), variance (v), skewness (s) and kurtosis (k). In scipy library of python, there is a function named `gengamma.pdf(x,a,c)` which generates distribution with non-zero skewness and kutosis. `a` and `c` are shape parameters.

After reading about this function, I come to know that generalized gamma distribution used in it is given by
$$P(x)=\frac{|c|x^{ca-1}\exp(-x^c)}{\Gamma(a)}$$

I want to know that how shape parameters are connected with $m,v,s$ and $k$.

[Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats/continuous_gengamma.html), relation for calculating $m$ and $s$ is given in terms of shape parameters but I couldn't get how can I calculate $s$ and $k$ in terms of shape parameters. Also, please give me some reference where this form of generalized gamma distribution is discussed in more details.

**Note**

I am writing this question is statistics instead of python community because I want to know more about how this distribution works.

Comment: With a look at [Wikipedia on 'Gamma Distribution'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) you can see that the skewness of a gamma distribution with shape parameter $\alpha$ is $1/\sqrt{\alpha}$ and that excess kurtosis is $6/\alpha.$ Roughly, a gamma distribution becomes more nearly normal as $\alpha$ increases. (There are also formulas for mean and variance in terms of gamma parameters.) What does that leave for you to investigate?

Comment: The page you link to in your question gives skewness and excess kurtosis already.